# jQuery form submit query parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm from Java and know nothing about jQuery, my application need to integrate with openid and i have to choose [openid-selector](http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/) as my client, it is a jQuery plugin that can send a form to server with query parameters, I hope to submit the form with additional

> openid_provider=google

query parameter pair according user's selection, how could i modify the js file to achieve this?

please see below demo:

http://openid-selector.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo.html

i know when i set openid.setDemoMode(false); and it will send request to server like below:

```
http://myserver/examples/consumer/try_auth.php?action=verify&openid_identifier=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fid
```

I want to add one query pair to this request mentioned above, how could i do that?

used file:

http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/source/browse/trunk/demo.html

http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/source/browse/trunk/js/openid-en.js

http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/source/browse/trunk/js/openid-jquery.js

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another hidden field inside the form e.g.,

```
<input type="hidden" name="param" value="value" />
```

Comment: I actually find the line to do the trick: it use $('#openid_form').append('<input type="hidden"d="' + this.input_id
+ '" name="' + this.input_id + '" value="'+ url + '"/>'); to add one input dynamically, following this i can add another parameter just as the same. Thanks anyway.